"Navigate in app" option in map is not working in android webview
I am working in android webview in that calling a website. In website there is one option named Direction, which redirect to map location. After redirect to google map in that one option was there named navigate in app by clicking on that it redirect to the google play store and indicating to install the google maps (while google maps is already installed in my phone) in the place of showing navigate the direction.
For more clear lets see the code and image,
Following is the link for redirect the map
<a href="https://maps.app.goo.gl/wzWRp23uj1JswLPBA" target="_blank"></a>

Image shows when click on Direction

Image show when click on Navigate in app


Can you post necessary part of webview code?
